# ¿Cómo filtrar y ordenar datos en archivos ".xlsx"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

He probado `openpyxl` pero solo configura el archivo y no filtra nada, también `xlsxwriter` pero crea nuevos archivos y no modifica los ya existentes.

Tengo que ordenar y filtrar datos.

El archivo contiene:

- Una columna ***distrito*** (1-6 distritos) tengo que filtrar el distrito 1
- Luego tiene una columna ***fecha*** tengo que  ordenar los datos del distrito cronológicamente.
- Tiene una columna ***nivel*** (1-9) la cual necesitaré el valor y agregar a un arreglo y repetir cada distrito.

Por ahora he logrado obtener los datos del distrito 1 pero no logro ordenarlos por la fecha. Esto es lo que estoy intentando:

```
def indiceCrimen():
    wbarch = load_workbook('p.xlsx')
    wsarch = wbarch.active
    colC = wsarch['C']
    crimenes = []
    distrito = 1
    for cell in colC:
        if not cell.value != distrito :

            crimenes.append(cell)

    numero = len(crimenes)
    i= 0
    while (i < numero):
        j = i
        while (j < numero):
            #%dd/%mm/%yy
            b =  wsarch[ 'A'+crimenes[i].coordinate.split("C")[1]].value
            a =  wsarch[ 'A'+crimenes[j].coordinate.split("C")[1]].value

            try:
                a = time.strptime(a, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
                b = time.strptime(b, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
            except:
                pass
            print("("+str(type(a))+") "+str(a)+"-------("+str(type(b))+") "+str(b))


            if a > b:
                temp = crimenes[i]
                crimenes[i] = crimenes[j]
                crimenes[j] = temp
            j= j+1
        i=i+1
```

Pero me lanza el siguiente error (la primera línea muestra los datos que se compararon):

```
   (<class 'str'>) 1/13/06 0:00-------(<class 'datetime.datetime'>) 2006-12-01 
   23:38:00
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "p1.py", line 66, in <module>
    indiceCrimen()
    File "p1.py", line 44, in indiceCrimen
     if a > b:
     TypeError: unorderable types: str() > datetime.datetime()
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Luis. Puedes hacerlo con openpyxls y filtrar creando tus propios métodos con Python y su biblioteca estándar. No obstante, mírate [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). Permite trabajar estructuras de datos de forma eficiente, operar, filtrar, ordenar, agrupar, etc y puede leer archivos de Excel de forma directa. La pregunta tal y como está es algo confusa y amplia, deberias intentar ser más específico y añadir un [mcve] junto a entrada y salida esperada. Un saludo.

Comment: Esto es una tarea Luis? Revisa [ask]

Comment: si tengo que generar una grafica de promedios de cada distrito pero no logro conseguir los datos de un distrito y luego ordenarlos cronológicamente  para mostrarlo en la grafica

Comment: Luis tal y como te comento deberías editar la pregunta agregando lo que estás intentando y un ejemplo mínimo pero real del xlsx junto a una salida esperada para ese ejemplo para poder reproducir el problema.  Si lo que te piden es graficar Pandas + Matplotlib es lo que necesitas (si te dejan usarlo). Es simple hacer lo que quieres pero serían necesarios más datos para poder ayudarte. Cargas el xlsx en un DataFrame, agrupas por distrito y luego ordenas por las fechas. Hecho esto solo te queda usar la columna nivel para graficar directamente o crear un array de NumPy o lista por cada distrito.

Comment: al principio no tenia gran cosa no sabia como empezar pero ahora es lo que tengo

Comment: Luis el error se debe a que en algún momento uno de los valores de `a` o  `b` es una cadena y no una fecha. Te estas complicando demasiado, si no puedes o quieres usar Pandas se puede hacer con Python pero para empezar deberias tratar con las filas como unidad. Una cosa importante es saber si la columna de fechas tiene formato de fecha en Excel, de ser así `openpyxl` ya lee esa columna y la pasa a tipo `datetime` por lo que se puede ordenar tal cual como una fecha usando la función `sorted`. Si es una cadena hay que parsearla primero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que comentas sobre la estructura de la hoja creo que te estas complicando demasiado. Como ya te he comentado la mejor forma de realizar lo que quieres es usar Pandas, no obstante se puede hacer con openpyxl y Python estándar aunque es más ineficiente, lo que será palpable si tu hoja tiene muchas filas.

Una opción es crear una matriz con las filas de la hoja usando listas anidadas. Hecho esto puedes ordenar (con `sorted` o `list.sort`)las filas en base a cualquier columna y agrupar (con `itertools.groupby`, `collections.defaultdict`, etc).

Para ver un ejemplo, supongamos que tenemos el siguiente xlsx llamado `datos.xlsx`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna A contiene la fecha (en formato Fecha reconocido por Excel), la columna B son los niveles y la columna C son los distritos.

Para obtener una lista con los niveles de cada distrito ordenados según la fecha podemos hacer algo como:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

# Cargamos el libro y la hoja correspondiente.
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'datos.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

# Obtenemos las filas iterando sobre la hoja.
filas = [[cell.value for cell in row] for row in ws.iter_rows()]

# Ordenamos las filas en función de la tercera columna primero (distrito) y en función de la primera después (fechas).
filas.sort(key = itemgetter(2, 0))

# Agrupamos en función de la tercera columna (distrito).
grupos = {k: list(v) for k, v in groupby(filas,  itemgetter(2))}
```

Con lo anterior tenemos un diccionario llamado grupos que tiene por claves los distritos y como valor las filas que tienen ese distrito ordenadas según la fecha:

```
{1: [[datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 23, 21, 45), 1, 1],
     [datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 8, 14, 53, 59, 999997), 8, 1],
     [datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 2, 22, 14, 0, 1), 3, 1]],

 2: [[datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 25, 18, 35, 0, 4), 9, 2],
     [datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 17, 2, 44, 59, 999997), 7, 2],
     [datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 26, 13, 21), 7, 2],
     [datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 21, 14, 26, 59, 999997), 2, 2]],

 3: [[datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 7, 4, 18, 59, 999999), 4, 3],
     [datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14, 14, 12, 59, 999999), 8, 3],
     [datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 14, 21, 58, 0, 2), 7, 3]],

 4: [[datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 12, 24, 0, 3), 3, 4],
     [datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 13, 11, 3, 59, 999999), 4, 4]]}
```

Si queremos obtener la segunda columna (niveles) basta con obtener la columna correspondiente de cada grupo:

```
for distrito,  filas in grupos.items():
    print("{} --> {}".format(distrito,  [fila[1] for fila in filas]))
```

**Salida:**

> 1 --> [1, 8, 3]
>   2 --> [9, 7, 7, 2]
>   3 --> [4, 8, 7]
>   4 --> [3, 4]

Si la columna de fechas no fuera reconocida como tal y tuviera cadenas y no fechas habría que parsearla adecuadamente usando la biblioteca `datetime`. Esto solo es a modo de ejemplo por si te sirve de idea para hacer lo que necesitas.

**Edición:**

Si la primera fila contiene los headers podemos ignorarla al leer usando el atributo `row_offset` del método `iter_rows` de la siguiente forma:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'datos.xlsx',  read_only=True)
ws = wb.active

filas = [[cell.value for cell in row] for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset= 1)]
filas.sort(key = itemgetter(2, 0))

grupos = {k: list(v) for k, v in groupby(filas,  itemgetter(2))}
```

Otra opción es simplemente eliminarla de la lista `filas`:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

wb = load_workbook(filename = '/home/sevilla/datos.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

filas = [[cell.value for cell in row] for row in ws.iter_rows()]
del filas[0]
filas.sort(key = itemgetter(2, 0))

grupos = {k: list(v) for k, v in groupby(filas,  itemgetter(2))}
```

Comment: entra en conflicto por que el archivo trae titulo en la primera fila  como evito que tome la primera fila

Comment: @LuisAlbertoAcosta mira la edición de la respuesta al final de la misma. Eso debería resolver tu problema. Lo he testado y  la primeara fila no es tenida en cuenta. Un saludo.

Comment: @ FJSevilla al momento de ordenar con sort muestra  el error TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()

Comment: @LuisAlbertoAcosta tal y como te comenté es difícil ayudar sin tener una muestra del xlsl. Debes asegurarte que la columna de fechas está parseada a datetime y que no existen filas que contengan otro tipo de datos (por ejemplo que alguna celda de Distrito contenga texto en vez de int). Imprime `filas` y comprueba las fechas y que no hay celdas con un tipo erróneo. Como te comento es difícil ser específico sin tener acceso al archivo para poder reproducir el error. Lo que es claro es que o en la columna distrito o fechas hay datos de distinto tipo.

Comment: hice pruebas y el ultima fila de la lista esta vacia todos sus valores NoneType y su tamaño 7858 y en excel dice que hay 7858 filas contando el titulo ya vi que agregaste borrar fila sera un sobrante la fila o no reconocio bien la ultima fila vi sus tipos de datos y estan correctos

Comment: @ FJSevilla de todas formas funciono por ultimo como obtener la posicion que tiene cada fila en el excel .Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si te refieres a dada una fila después de ordenar saber el número de fila que ocupaba en el excel original puedes crear una nueva columna en cada fila de la lista `filas` para guardar este dato. Por ejemplo: `filas = [[cell.value for cell in row] + [row[0].row] for row in ws.iter_rows()]`, Con esto cda fila tiene una cuarta columna que indica su numero de fila en el excel. Por ejemplo la fila `[datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 23, 21, 45), 1, 1, 5] ` estaba situada en la fila 5 del excel.Se podria filtrar y ordenar guardando en esta lista las filas en sí y no sus valores aunque complica el código.